# Finding the largest difference between angles in an Array

Tags: algorithm, math, accelerometer

I'm working with some accelerometer data that's an array of values between -180 and 180.  Representing angles in degrees.

Is there a clever algorithm to find the largest difference between any two of the angles?

Comment: clever? you mean like sort them and then take a[1] and a[N]

Comment: The data is circular, 180 = -180.  So finding the min and max isn't enough.

Comment: so convert first, and then sort.

Comment: Define "largest difference"? What is the largest difference, for example, between angle X and angle X? Is it 0? is it 360? is it a particular integer multiple of 360?

Comment: The difference between angle X and itself would be 0.  We're looking for the pair that come closest to 180 degrees apart (since it's impossible to get more than that).

Answer (score 4):

There should really be a lot of angles in order to worry about it. But sure, you can beat O(n^2)

Sort the array. Step through with pointers `a` and `b`. First find the `b` that makes the largest angle from `a` and store it to `best`. Then repeatedly advance `a` by one and step `b` until it stops increasing the difference. You will traverse the list about 1.5 times total, bounded at O(n), because `b` cannot step past `a`. So it's no worse than the time it takes for sorting.

Comment: I think you've got the right answer here, but it could do with a bit more explanation to separate it from the "sort and pick the first and last" suggestions. For example you could show why, for a sorted array `A`, if `A[j]` has the greatest angular difference from `A[i]` and `A[k]` has the greatest angular difference from `A[i+1]` that `k >= j`. This is what really prevents you from having to search through the O(n^2) pairs.

Answer (score 1):

Say an angle is positive if it's in [0, 180], and it's negative, if in [-180, 0].

Scan the list, do the followings:
1 record the largest and smallest positive angles
2 record the largest and smallest negative angles
3 if an angle is a positive angle, convert it (letting it subtract 180) to a negative angle, and mark it with some flag to indicate it comes from conversion

For #1, the largest difference is simply the biggest angle subtract the smallest angle. So is for #2.

For #3, sort angles first. Scanning from an end of sorted list. If adjacent angles are of different kinds(one is from conversion, one is not), then calculate the difference. If the difference is the smallest one ever met, record it, and keep scanning. When done, use 180 - difference, and let the result be the difference #3.

Now you have 3 difference, pick the largest one. I think it's the answer.

For complexity, all scanning is O(n). For sorting, if all angles are positive or negative, it needs no phase #3 at all. If phase #3 is needed, we can let it have less angles. For example, if the list has less positive angles, we can convert positive into negative, and vice versa. Sorting is O(nlgn), but we can have smaller n.

Comment: You could also skip the converting, and have two scanners: one starting at the beginning of the positive angles, and one at the beginning of the negative angles.

Answer (score 0):

Got this from a RW tutorial.

Its the opposite of what you want (returns the smallest angle), but you could tweak it.

```
// Returns shortest angle between two angles,
// between -M_PI and M_PI

static inline CGFloat ScalarShortestAngleBetween(const CGFloat a, const CGFloat b)
{
    CGFloat difference = b - a;
    CGFloat angle = fmodf(difference, M_PI * 2);
    if (angle >= M_PI)
    {
        angle -= M_PI * 2;
    }
    return angle;
}
```

Comment: This is missing the point.  OP can already find the difference between two angles (we assume).  We're looking for the largest angle returned, hopefully without going through the obvious `O(n^2)` process of all pairwise conversions.